# Line Plot in R with two y-axes using twoord.plot: Values of first y-axis missing

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I wanted to create a plot with two different y-axes using the code below:

```
twoord.plot(lx = stack_question$year, ly = stack_question$size, ry =stack_question$density , rx = stack_question$year)
```

However, the y-axis on the lefthand side misses the values. What is the best way to resolve that issue?

[image]

My dataset looks like this.

```
 year size    density
1 1975  144 0.06116022
2 1980  164 0.10030097
3 1985  168 0.11203907
4 1990  171 0.14876726
5 1995  173 0.15874613
6 2000  192 0.21369396
7 2005  193 0.23662855
8 2010  195 0.29243307
9 2015  196 0.30810454
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add limits for the left axe:

```
lylim=c(100,200)
```